# Don't Move Table View Cells with a Long Press Gesture on specific position

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I've completely implemented the UILongGesture in my App which exchanges the cell value by drag and drop. For now I've requirement that if I move first row with last row then first row should remain at first position means don't want change the position.

I've tried chunk of codes and wasted my time but couldn't get result. Below is my code.

```
- (IBAction)longPressGestureRecognized:(id)sender{

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGesture = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;
UIGestureRecognizerState state = longGesture.state;
CGPoint location = [longGesture locationInView:self.tblTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tblTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

static UIView *snapshotView = nil;
static NSIndexPath *sourceIndexPath = nil;

switch (state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        if (indexpath) {
            sourceIndexPath = indexpath;
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
            snapshotView = [self customSnapshotFromView:cell];
            __block CGPoint center = cell.center;
            snapshotView.center = center;
            snapshotView.alpha = 0.0;
            [self.tblTableView addSubview:snapshotView];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

                center.y = location.y;
                snapshotView.center = center;
                snapshotView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
                snapshotView.alpha = 0.98;

                cell.alpha = 0.0;

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                cell.hidden = YES;
            }];
        }
        break;

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
        CGPoint center = snapshotView.center;
        center.y = location.y;
        snapshotView.center = center;

        if (indexpath && ![NSIndexPath isEqual:sourceIndexPath]) {

    [self.namesArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row withObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];

            [self.tblTableView moveRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:indexpath];

            sourceIndexPath = indexpath;

            NSIndexPath *indexPathOfLastItem =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.namesArray count] - 1) inSection:0];
            NSLog(@"last :::: %@",indexPathOfLastItem);

            if (indexpath==indexPathOfLastItem) {
                [self.namesArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:indexPathOfLastItem.row withObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
                [self.tblTableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfLastItem toIndexPath:0];

                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
                cell.hidden = NO;
                cell.alpha = 0.0;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    default: {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
        cell.hidden = NO;
        cell.alpha = 0.0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

            snapshotView.center = cell.center;
            snapshotView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            snapshotView.alpha = 0.0;
            cell.alpha = 1.0;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            sourceIndexPath = nil;
            [snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
            snapshotView = nil;

        }];

        break;
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: What I have come across is the cell is not exchanging that's what I want but it is hidden. Here is the image: [Image1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jr0adgnsfkrpapk/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2009-May-2015%204.18.59%20pm.png?dl=0) and [Image2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbyozmrp23q4yu5/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2009-May-2015%204.20.00%20pm.png?dl=0)

Comment: `if (indexpath && ![NSIndexPath isEqual:sourceIndexPath])` What is the `NSIndexPath` doing there? it doesn't seem right. Maybe, `if (indexpath && ![indexpath isEqual:sourceIndexPath])`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you should do the row exchanges in `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` but instead in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` is processed rapidly(many many times) while you are long pressing and moving your finger across the screen. So this causes the row exchange code to run many times which is not your intention I guess. `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` are run once per each longpress.

I would keep these following three lines of code in `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` and move the rest to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`:

```
CGPoint center = snapshotView.center;
center.y = location.y;
snapshotView.center = center;
```

The `UIGestureRecognizerState`s are as follows:

```
UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible,   // the recognizer has not yet recognized its gesture, but may be evaluating touch events. this is the default state
UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan,      // the recognizer has received touches recognized as the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop
UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged,    // the recognizer has received touches recognized as a change to the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop
UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded,      // the recognizer has received touches recognized as the end of the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop and the recognizer will be reset to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible
UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled,  // the recognizer has received touches resulting in the cancellation of the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop. the recognizer will be reset to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible
UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed,     // the recognizer has received a touch sequence that can not be recognized as the gesture. the action method will not be called and the recognizer will be reset to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible
```

And instead of using `switch`s `default:`, I believe it will be better to cover more of these states in your state machine logic.

Comment: I did tried in UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded but nothing worked.

Comment: Nij can you upload your code to gitHub and post the reprisotory in here please? Its hard to tell something with this much code

Answer (score 0):

When your finger detaches from the screen during animation, iOS returns `gesture.state = UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible`.

So remember to handle that gesture!